# How I can read private MSMQ of remote server by passing credentials to read from that queue?

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to connect remote server private queue. I want to read and save the messages in string. below is the code

```
        MessageQueue rmTxnQ = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=TCP:IP\\private$\\queuename");
        rmTxnQ.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        System.Messaging.Message msgTxn = rmTxnQ.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
        MessageBox.Show(msgTxn.Body.ToString());
```

Thanks,
Megha

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Remote server is password protected

Comment: How do you password-protect an MSMQ queue?

Comment: I tried to check properties of that queue. My code is not working even if i unchecked authenticated checkbox.